# Json Object Property

Tags: node.js, json, express, object, pug

I wanna parse just title. I used express, body-parse and pug. this is my code:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {

   try {
       const posts = await Post.find()
       res.render('post', {title: posts })
   }
   catch (err){
       res.json({errors:err})
   }
})
```

[][1]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Qa1m.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
    let posts = await Post.find()
    posts = posts.pop()
    res.render('post', {title: posts['title'], description: posts['description']} )
}
```